# Why does my function throw a TypeError; num() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ip'?

Tags: python, random

My goal is to create a random int (1-254) but keep getting the unexpected keyword argument error when trying to use click. What am I doing wrong?

```
import click
from random import randint as r

@click.command()
@click.option("--ip", default="192.168.0.1", help="IP Address")
@click.option('--host', default="www.google.com" , help="Host URL")
def num(self):
    x = r(1,254)
    click.echo(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click-decorated function needs to accept the options you've defined as parameters.  Also, `self` is idiomatically the name of the parameter for the object on which instance methods are called but you've defined a free function.

Note my changes to your `def` line:

```
import click
from random import randint as r

@click.command()
@click.option("--ip", default="192.168.0.1", help="IP Address")
@click.option('--host', default="www.google.com" , help="Host URL")
def num(ip, host):
    x = r(1,254)
    click.echo(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num()
```